# Event to catch submitting all forms in shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am trying to add functionality that will save data from forms in the database. My problem is to detect the submission of all types of forms. I see there are some events like `ContactFormEvent` etc. but what in the case of custom forms? Maybe there is one combined event that is catching all submissions? `FormEvent`? or `SubmitFormEvent`?

Comment: You might add some more information about your goal. What are you trying to achieve with the subscriber for such an event?